# Waiting until the control is activated error in testcomplete

Tags: testcomplete

I am able to click on Email link but not able to enter the username and test Complete shows *"Waiting until the control is activate"* only.

```
var UserName = returnScreenPortal().ParentalLockViewNavigator.LoginForm.Username;
UserName.Click(180 , 40);
UserName.Keys("jcasale@rosettastone.com");
var Password = returnScreenPortal().ParentalLockViewNavigator.LoginForm.Password;
Password.Click(180 , 40);
Password.Keys("password");
```

Comment: You can edit your question and add to it the code you wrote in your comment. It will be easier to read (and help you) that way.

Comment: When TestComplete clicks the button, does a new window appear in the tested application? Does TestComplete continue executing the test if you close this window manually?

Comment: @DmitryNikolaev : No new window open and yes if i close the browser window execution continues

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are facing the situation that is described in the [Calling Methods Asynchronously](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/56676/) help topic. You need to click the email link asynchronously using the [CallObjectMethodAsync](http://smartbear.com/viewarticle/55108/) method as it is described in the topic.

Comment: I am able to click on Email link  
@DmitryNikolaev 

but not able to enter the values. Please Help

Comment: So, have you tried to call the Click method asynchronously? How does it work?